# How to execute jquery on page update

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, html, django

I have used jquery multi-select to render my django app muslitiselect in an user friendly way. When My Page First render I have putted script given below on page, this script bind any element having class multiselect to jquery multiselect.

```
$(function() {
      $(".multiselect").multiselect();
     }
);
```

Now I have rendered few divs, and when user click on edit page Query render these divs with bounded forms using.

```
function inline_modal_form(href, data) {
        url = '.';
        modal_link = '#' + String(href);
        $(modal_link).load(url, data);
    }
```

Now when new form rendered have element having class multiselect, but can not get bind with jquery multiselect. How Can I execute this script when ever my page update.

I have searched for methods like .on(previously .live, .delegate) but could not understood How to execute my script.

Jquery 1.8

Comment: How about when...http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of calling the plugin directly in the root code, wrap it in a function and call that:

```
var bindMultiselects = function () {
    $(".multiselect").multiselect();
};

$(function() {
    bindMultiselects();
    // any other page load code, etc.
});
```

Then, when you load the new content, call that function again:

```
function inline_modal_form(href, data) {
    url = '.';
    modal_link = '#' + String(href);
    $(modal_link).load(url, data, bindMultiselects);
}
```

Of course, this only works if the act of initializing the plugin has no side-effects if called twice.  It *shouldn't*, but I can't be certain.  If that's the case, then you'll need a better selector than `".multiselect"` because you'd need to distinguish only the elements that were just dynamically added, not the ones which have already been initialized with the plugin.

Answer (score 3):

There is no plugin delegation, delegation is for event binding.

In your case, you should use load callback function:

```
function inline_modal_form(href, data) {
    url = '.';
    modal_link = '#' + String(href);
    $(modal_link).load(url, data, function () {
        $(modal_link).find('.multiselect').multiselect();
    });
}
```

Comment: upvoted as your solution worked, but will have to accept @David response as answer for better structuring.Thanks a lot